# twitter-bootstrap tooltips нужна помошь.

Tags: twitter, bootstrap

Не работают `tooltips`. Помогите, что там и где нужно написать, чтобы заработало? Стили и Js подключены.

```
<!-- javascript -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
```

Comment: ну там же есть еще много чего кроме подсказок. Или остальное можно такой же функцией вызывать только немного изменяя ?

Comment: да, всё внутри ready-функции $(function(){...здесь...}), к тому же у bootstrap`а довольно неплохая документация, читайте, пробуйте, разбирайтесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

далее в скрипте:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').tooltip({
        selector: "[rel=tooltip]", // можете использовать любой селектор
        placement: "top" 
    });
});
```

теперь при наведении на любой элемент в теле документа с атрибутом `rel` равному "tooltip", тултип будет всплывать со значением в атрибете `title`:

```
<p>this is <strong rel="tooltip" title="This Is Tooltip">tooltip</strong></p>
```

Comment: не работает, стандартный тайтл вылазиет и все(((

$(function() {
    $('body').tooltip({
        selector: "[rel=tooltip]", // можете использовать любой селектор
        placement: "top" 
    });
});

прописывал и в head и в body

Comment: у меня всё прекрасно работает, правда подключено одним файлом, попробуйте и вы. а как на счёт остальных скриптов на странице? как на счёт ошибок в консоле?

Comment: $ is not defined
index.html()index.html (строка 82)
[Прерывать на этой ошибке]  

$(function() {
такая ошибка в консоли. я просто не юзаю Js и не знаю ничего ((

Comment: ну так у вас проблема не в бутстрапе, а в jQuery где-то в строке 82

>я просто не юзаю Js и не знаю ничего

так может стоит попытаться узнать?

Comment: в консоли ошибка ведет на эту функцию которую вы мне написали. больше никаких функций нет.

Comment: всё работает. просто ставил функцию выше всех Js, дошло до меня наконецто, а есть еше у вас другие функцию для будстрапа ?

Comment: >а есть еше у вас другие функцию для будстрапа

в смысле?